# Why am i getting not great compression with zlib?

Tags: c++, compression, zip, zlib

By default i output a file that is 120mb. Here i have a input and output buffer thats double that. When i run this code i get an output of 10mb (default gives me 11mb). When i zip the raw 128mb file i get 700kb. Why am i getting 11mb instead of <1mb like zip gives me? Using 7-zip manager i asked it to compress with gzip using deflate and it give me a 4.6mb file which is still much smaller. I'm very curious why this is happening. It feels like i am doing something wrong.

```
static UInt32 len=0;
static char buf[1024*1024*256];
static char buf2[1024*1024*256];
static char *curbuf=buf;
z_stream strm;
void initzstuff()
{
    strm.zalloc = 0;
    strm.zfree = 0;
    strm.opaque = 0;
    int ret = deflateInit(&strm, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return;
}

void flush_file(MyOstream o, bool end){
    strm.avail_in = len;
    strm.next_in = (UInt8*)buf;
    strm.avail_out = sizeof(buf2);
    strm.next_out = (UInt8*)buf2;
    int ret = deflate(&strm, (end ? Z_FINISH : Z_NO_FLUSH));
    assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);
    int have = sizeof(buf2) - strm.avail_out;
    fwrite(buf2, 1, have, o);
    if(end)
    {
        (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
    }
    len=0;
    curbuf=buf;
/*
    fwrite(buf, 1, len, o);
    len=0;
    curbuf=buf;
//*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip can use Deflate64 or other compression algorithm (like BZip2), and when your file is very sparce that can result in such difference.
Also, standard for ZLib tells only about the format of compressed data, and how the data is compressed is chosen by archivators, so 7-zip can use some heuristics which makes the ouput smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Probably chunk-size? [zlib.net/zpipe.c](http://zlib.net/zpipe.c) gives a fairly good example.

You'll probably get better performance too if you chunk rather than try to do the entire stream.

Comment: ummm what? did you even look at my code? my chunk size aka buffer size is way bigger.